# nVidia Optimus - switch graphic card without logout

Tags: drivers, intel-graphics, nvidia-optimus

I'm happy user of [MSI GP60 Leopard](http://www.msi.com/product/nb/GP60-2PE-Leopard.html). It has Intel HD Graphics 4600 and nVidia GeForce 840M. Official driver downloaded from nVidia website doesn't work. After install X server hangs right after login attempt. But after adding Xorg-Edgers PPA repo and install suggested driver works everything. I also installed Prime Indicator to switch gfx card but it's force me to logout and login again.

**And here is a question**: is it possible to switch gfx card without logout? Or is it possible to switch it automagically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed Bumblebee and switching to nVidia works on demand with optirun. Problem solved somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it without logout for now.

Comment: Anything new on this?

Comment: How about bumblebee?